# Laravel using subdomain as parameter in route

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have an Laravel application that can be accessed by multiple subdomains, so I configured a route group for this and inside that route group I've created a route to access one of my controllers.
The route is as follows:

```
    Route::group(['domain' => '{account}.domain.com'], function() {
        Route::get('foobar/{param}', 'MyController@foobar');
    })
```

MyController@foobar is like this

```
        public function foobar($param) {
            return $param;
        }
```

When I make a request to 'mysub.domain.com/foobar/sometext' I expected the value of $param to be 'sometext' but it's actually 'mysub' from the subdomain.

If change the route and the controller to expect more parameters the first parameter is always the subdomain.

How can I make the controller stop receving the subdomain as the first param and just receive 'sometext'?

Comment: why not try `foobar($account,$param)`?

Comment: Tried that and it works, thanks. but i'll have an useless params on every controller (i'll have a few more like this).

Comment: it's not useless why you consider it useless ? it will only save you time checking the Subdomain and some bytes you don't write `$account` in arguments of methods. Also you can access route parameters from controller and avoid defining any arguments in methods.